# Where is httpd.conf file of a domain? (Plesk, Apache, CentOS, Dedicated Server.)

Tags: centos, apache, plesk, dedicated-server

I'm trying to disable access logging (access_log) for domains. I can't find a way to do it yet, I thought if httpd.conf file exist of a domain maybe I can look into that. So do you know where is httpd.conf file of a domain?

Comment: Try `locate httpd.conf` (Note that in newer Apache setups, the configuration is spread across multiple files, but they won't be far from where you find httpd.conf.)

Comment: Thank you!!! I spent 4~ hours before.. damn..

Comment: No problem. If it helped, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: /etc/httpd/conf.d/zz010_psa_httpd.conf

Leads you to find httpd.include paths for domains!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
locate httpd.conf
```

on the commend line.
Note that in newer Apache setups, the configuration is spread across multiple files, but they won't be far from where you find httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but reading @user1055645 comment in the question, about follow the file:

`/etc/httpd/conf.d/zz010_psa_httpd.conf`

I found the configuration file here:

> /etc/httpd/conf/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/domain.com.conf

If you want to **disable** access_log you can edit this file and comment with an **#** the beginning of this line:

`CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/system/giornalone.it/logs/access_log plesklog`

At the end **restart** apache server to make the changes take effect.